# Is there an eager "inserting" option in laravel for ManyToMany attach?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

Is there a way to reduce many **Insert** queries to 1 when using Laravel's attach function in ManyToMany relationship?

Here is my code:

```
$itemIds = Item::pluck('id');

$sale = Sale::create();

foreach ($itemIds as $id) {
    $sale->items()->attach($id);
}
```

But this way it makes as many queries as items found in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Attaching / Detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

> For convenience, attach and detach also accept arrays of IDs as input.

For example:

```
$user = User::find(1);
 
$user->roles()->attach([1, 2, 3]);
```

In your code, you have to use `$itemIds` as array of Item Id.

```
$itemIds = Item::pluck('id');

$sale = Sale::create();

$sale->items()->attach($itemIds);
```